# excel dim cell text value as controls

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am having trouble with my macro. I have a button and a few check boxes on a form, i am trying to write a code that when i click the button it will check the range("A1").text, after take that text (which in this case is "checkbox1") and i want to say something like this:

```
questionnaire = Range("A1").Text
questionnaire.Value = Range("A2").Value
```

since i have many checkboxes as mentioned earlier, i want that when i write a certain controls name in "A1", when i click the button, that control will take the value in "A2". the problem is i do not know what i should DIM questionnaire as. please help

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to show the value of the checkbox in A2 - based on the checkbox number from A1?

Comment: let's say that in cell "A1" it contains the text "checkbox1" and in cell "A2" it contains the value "1", when i click the button, i want whatever is in cell "A1" which is my "checkbox1" to have a value of "1" which mean that checkbox1.value = true

Comment: Are they **Forms** checkboxes or **ActiveX** checkboxes

Comment: Your question still sounds a bit vague.  A few questions: What kind of values are you obtaining from A2?  Why doesn't a String work?  Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CB = Sheets(3).Range("A1").Value
    CBVal = Sheets(3).Range("A2").Value

    For Each contr In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" And contr.Name = CB Then
            contr.Value = CBVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Make sure you type in the correct **Name** in A1.

[image]

Comment: If you load the UserForm in modeless form, then you would be able to change any of the 4 checkboxes. Simply enter the name in A1 and click the button.

Comment: Thank you very much, but just a quick question, what did you dim CB, CBval as?

Comment: Haven't Dimmed them ... so they would be Variant. But based on your query, you can dim CB as String and CBVal as Int or Bool.

Comment: also, what did you dim contr as? is that variant as well? or do i dim it as control?

Comment: For Each stores each elements of the collection/object one by one into the variable ... so it can be anything. Since your collection returns individual objects, you can dim it as object. But, best bet is to simple dim it to tackle mismatch errors.